# Python Dictionary return requested key if value does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for an easy way to be able to get a value from a dictionary, and if its not there, return the key that the user passed in.

E.g.:

```
>>> lookup = defaultdict(magic)
>>> print lookup['DNE']
'DNE'
>>> print lookup.get('DNE')
'DNE'
>>> print lookup['exists']
'some other value'
>>> print lookup.get('exists')
'some other value'
```

These will always be strings, but basically I am creating a language map and need an easy way to get a value, if it exists return it else return the key.

Is there any easy way to do this?  Or should I just extend dict and do it manually.

Comment: I was going to suggest extending dict.  That's the right approach IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be possible with a lambda function

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict((lambda : 'DNE'))
```

Edit: Sorry I misread the question. As the comment above already said. The way to go is extending the dict class.

```
>>> class mydict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self,key):
...         return key
... 
>>> a = mydict()
>>> a['asd']
'asd'
```

Comment: I never knew there was a missing... this does not work with a.get('asd')

Comment: Could be named `defaultkeydict`.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think `defaultdict` will help you here because the function that generates the default value does not have access to which key was requested.

However you use an ordinary dictionary and use [`get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a default value:

```
>>> lookup = {}
>>> key = 'DNE'
>>> lookup.get(key, key)
'DNE'
```

Comment: So in short I should just extend dict, and override get and __item__ ?

Comment: @Nix: If you want to extend dict then I think you could use the solution posted by Moe. My answer shows how you can do it without extending dict.

Comment: Your solution doesn't help me, i am trying to get around having to use get with a default.

Comment: I like this solution a lot; It avoids polluting the codebase with a whole extra (small) class, at the expense of writing `d.get(k,k)` instead of `d[k]` when one desires the pass-through behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This works under Python 2.7 at least:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class KeyAwareDefaultDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        self[key] = value = self.default_factory(key)
        return value

lookup = KeyAwareDefaultDict((lambda key: key))
```

Unlike the standard dict, defaultdict.get() seems to call __missing__ too, so it makes a better base for extension.